# rails4 rspec how to use have_selector properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am having trouble using the have_selector function properly. 
This is what is show on the page.

```
<div class+"alert alert-error"> You are not authorized to edit that user </div>
```

which I want to select, using

```
expect(page).to have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'You are not authorized to edit that user')
```

but the above line does not seem to correctly pick up the text displayed on the page. 
what is the correct way?  thanks.

Comment: Your HTML seems invalid. Are you that's how it is being generated?

Comment: @Surya sorry for the confusion. it is corrected now.

Comment: I corrected the html before being "put on hold." Is this still an invalid question?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error with your HTML syntax, the example below should work fine:

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert">You are not authorized to edit that user</div>
```

**Rspec**

```
expect(page).to have_selector('div.alert', text: 'You are not authorized to edit that user')
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i corrected it